# Foreach loop with export-csv in Powershell working for first field, but not other fields

Tags: powershell, foreach, powershell-remoting, export-csv

I have a PS script that reads a .txt file of pcnames, checks remote registry to report back on the installed programs.  It's partially working when I export it to a .csv file, however only the pcname field changes to the next pcname from my .txt file.   The .csv file is duplicating the same list of installed programs that the first pc in the list has installed.  I'm not sure why it is outputting the pcname for each different pc correctly, but the installed program list and version is duplicated for every pc when I view the .csv file.  I've tried changing the location of the foreach loops, but haven't had any luck.  Thanks for any suggestions.  Here's the code:

```
$pcnames = Get-Content "C:\scripts\pclist.txt"

foreach ($pcname in $pcnames) {


$list=@()
$InstalledSoftwareKey="SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall"
$InstalledSoftware=[microsoft.win32.registrykey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$pcname)
$RegistryKey=$InstalledSoftware.OpenSubKey($InstalledSoftwareKey) 
$SubKeys=$RegistryKey.GetSubKeyNames()

Foreach ($key in $SubKeys){
$thisKey=$InstalledSoftwareKey+"\\"+$key
$thisSubKey=$InstalledSoftware.OpenSubKey($thisKey)
$obj = New-Object PSObject
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ComputerName" -Value $pcname
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DisplayName" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("DisplayName"))
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DisplayVersion" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("DisplayVersion"))
$list += $obj 
}
$list | where { $_.DisplayName } | select ComputerName, DisplayName, DisplayVersion | Export-csv 'c:\scripts\allprograms111722.csv' -append
}
```

I adjusted the closing } for both foreach loops, thinking that would fix the issue, but it did not.

Answer (score 0):

Your script works for me. To be sure that you are not using the content read from the previous computer if a computer in the list is unreachable, you should clear variables between each loop :

```
$list=@()
clear-variable InstalledSoftware
clear-variable SubKeys
clear-variable RegistryKey
```